# plt.hist() only for certain frequency; Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge DataFrame ('df') with different columns from which one stores names as string values ('name'). Now, I would like to simply plot a histogram with the frequency of each name within the DataFrame. However, the data contains thousands of unique names and that's why I would like to only plot a histogram for names from a certain frequency on:

```
df.name.value_counts() > 100
```

Can I give this kind of filter/mask to the plot? I already tried to use the 'range' argument in plt.hist():

```
plt.hist(df['name'], range=[100, 151]);
```

But it still displays all other names but without their frequency…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `df.name.value_counts()` returns the content of your histogram. This return value can be masked using the usual expressions.

```
name_frequencies = df.name.value_counts()
most_freq_name_freqs = name_frequencies[name_frequencies > 100]
```

To draw a histogram of data which is already *histogrammed*, it is useful to use `plt.hist` with the `weights` argument.

```
plt.hist(most_freq_name_freqs.index, weights=most_freq_name_freqs)
```

By doing this you create a histogram with a single entry per bin, but the bin content is scaled by the weight. Since the weights are the precomputed frequencies, you get the histogram of name frequencies.